# Drag and drop in PhoneGap and Jquery Mobile

Tags: android, jquery-ui, cordova, jquery-mobile, drag-and-drop

I searched around thread and I found out to drag and drop in mobile need to use Jquery UI and use prevent default to do it but mine don't works. I tried UI touch punch it still won't work either and I not sure which step I have been missing out. My screen in mobile is drag up and down  and sometimes get miss a drag action from LogCat.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

JS File

```
 $( document ).delegate("#game", "pageshow", function() {
  $('.box0').draggable();
  $('.box1').draggable();
  $('.box2').draggable();
  $('body>div').bind("dragstart", function(event, ui){
      event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can see this http://forresst.github.com/2012/06/22/Make-a-list-jQuery-Mobile-sortable-by-drag-and-drop/

I don't know if it works on PhoneGap

Comment: Hi Foresst, could you post some of the code in here? It's better to have the information in stackoverflow itself, as external links tend to change over time and your solution might get lost.

Comment: Mine is not a drag and drop list but an object. I had try the drop in Jq UI but fail to work.